# ImageUrl from a site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a site called www.suporteaocorretor.com. In this site the users edit all informations necessary. All directories are created in this site according to the user. If the user is uploading a photo it is saved in this site. All the data is saved in a SQL Server database.

For each user I created a template (chosen by then) that is hosted in any domain. This template is used to anybody which is interested to buy rent a house. This template uses all the information from my site suporteaocorretor. I did that to have low costs. Everything is all right. But I am having problems to "Read" the images. When I upload a image, I use:

```
Server.mappath("~" + /user/images/filename.jpg)
```

So when I use imageurl from the template I am not "seeing" it. Can you help me?
I use c# with Asp.net vs 2013. all my code are made in code behind.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include in the question the relevant template markup and the lines of code where you set the image URL?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
img.ImageUrl = "~/user/images/filename.jpg"
```

or this:

```
img.ImageUrl = "user/images/filename.jpg"
```

where `img` is your Image control, and `user` and `filename` are replaced by their actual values.